# Hide/Unhide <div> on back button html jquery iOS Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, ios

I am having an issue where I have a processing animation that appears after the user clicks the button where form then post data and redirects to another page.  Problem is when the user clicks the back button, instead of the submit reappearing, the processing animation is stuck in a loop. I was able to solve this problem by using meta tags to disable caching for windows and android users but not working for iOS. Any help would be great thank you.

```
<div id="processing-image" style="display:none;">
<img src="images/processing-image.gif" alt="Processing" />
</div><!-- end processing-image -->
<div      id="submitButtonHolder" class="form-group">
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Receive Invite</button>
```

here is where i hide and unhide upon successful form submit.

```
complete: function(){
    $('#processing-image').show();
    $('#submitButtonHolder').hide();
```

If I do the reverse and hide then show before redirect, it solves the problem. However, it changes before user is redirected and looks really bad.

thanks again